# Algebraic Proof that the Amplitude does not affect Frequency

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, physics, relations

In Simple Harmonic Motion, the Amplitude is defined as the maximum displacement.  Consider a pendulum (SHM) or a mass on a  horizontal or vertical spiring.  If the amplitude increases, which means that the height or starting distance becomes greater, the frequency AND period both do not change.  I am looking for an algebraic proof that can show  how the amplitude doesn't actually affect the period.

Comment: Consider the zeroes of the function and how the transformation $f(x) \to af(x)$ acts on the wave with $a$ a real number.

Answer (score 1):

As CyclotomicField proposed in the comments, if you model your wave as a function $f(t)$ a change of amplitude corresponds to the re-scaling by a positive number $a$. This rescaling doesn't affect the zeroes of the function at all, so the distances between the zeroes, i.e. the period, doesn't change either.

Answer (score 0):

For the mass-spring system, the equation of motion reads:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0
&=m\ddot{x}+kx\\
&=\left(D_{t}-j\omega_{n}\right)\left(D_{t}+j\omega_{n}\right)x
\end{aligned}
$$

where $D_{t}$ is the time differential operator and $\omega_{n}=\sqrt{k/m}$.
Simplifying the procedure a little here, we have either

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &= \left(D_{t}-j\omega_{n}\right)x \implies x=C_{1}\cdot e^{j\omega_{n}t}
\\\\
&\text{or} \\\\
0 &= \left(D_{t}+j\omega_{n}\right)x \implies x=C_{2}\cdot e^{-j\omega_{n}t}
\end{aligned}
$$

Combining the two homogenous solutions:

$$
x=C_{1}\cdot e^{j\omega_{n}t} + C_{2}\cdot e^{-j\omega_{n}t}
$$

The thing to notice here is that **any** constants $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ satisfy the equation of motion, their values only depend on the initial conditions and are independent of the frequency $\omega_{n}$.